# OSX: Running multiple instances of an application with different arguments

Tags: macos

I need to run multiple instances of Google Chrome but with different arguments.

What I have tried:

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --some-param-A
```

Fine, a new instance of Chrome is launched. Checking the command line parameters using *chrome://version* is also OK, **--some-param-A** is there.

Now I would like to open a second instance but with different command line parameters.

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --some-param-B
```

A second instance is launched, but it is started with **--some-param-A** again. I need it to start with **--some-param-B** though.

I also tried the -F (--fresh) option, did not help either. Seems that arguments after --args are read only once.

How can I fix that? 
Thanks!

Comment: This is more likely to be a Chrome limitation than a bug in open. For example, it works fine with Firefox (using different arguments in different launches).

Comment: Can you be clearer about your arguments? This works fine `open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args http://ibm.com --new-window` followed by `open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args http://hp.com --new-window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing --user-data-dir to Chrome when you launch it from the command line?

It seems to be a known issue and using --user-data-dir (without a specified directory) is a workaround.

Works Cited:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/35392/how-to-launch-a-new-instance-of-google-chrome-from-the-command-line

Comment: Hey, thank you, it helped! The only difference is that I had to specify some directory for --user-data-dir. I used --user-data-dir=/tmp/xxx.